# magento 2 : filter grid based on vendor

Tags: magento2, grid, multi-vendor

i have created

> - role as **vendor** with product and sales grid access
> - custom product attributes as **vendor_id** and assign a particular vendor to products using this
> - custom order attributes as **vendor_id** (i have spit the order based on vendor and assign vendor_id using custom order attributes)

when any user **login as vendor** i want to show only `associated products` and order in grids, is thare any conman class or anything from where i can `filter` for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\User\Api\Data;

class yourclass{

  protected $_user;
  protected $_customerSession;
  protected $_productCollection;

  public function __construct(

    Data $user,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
  )
  {
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_user = $user;
    $this->_productCollection = $collectionFactory;
  }

  public function getVendorId() { 

      if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this->_user->getId();
      }  
  }

  public function yourfunction{

      $vendorId = $this->getVendorId();

      if($vendorId){

         $collection = $this->_productCollection->create()->addFieldToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id',  $vendorId);

      }
      // you will get your product collection
  }

//for order collection

namespace 'YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME_SPACE';

class YOURCALSS extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    protected $_user;

    public function __construct(
        Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    Data $user,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory 
    ) {

        $this->_user = $user;
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function getVendorId() { 

        return $this->_user->getId();

    }

    public function YOURFUNCTION()
    {
      $vendorId = $this->getVendorId();

      if($vendorId){
         $collection = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
         // You Can filter collection as 
         $this->orderCollectionFactory->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id',  $vendorId);

      }
    }      
}
```

Comment: let me know if any issues